# Outer measure discontinuous from below

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

I was trying to find an example of an outer Measure which is not continuous from below. 
These are the definitions I use

> An outer measure on $X$ is a function $\mu^\ast: \mathcal{P}(X)\to [0,\infty]$ if 
>   it fulfills
>
> - $\mu^\ast(\emptyset)=0$
> - $\mu^\ast\Big( \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\Big) \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty A_j$

And an outer measure is continuous from below when for the sequence
$(A_j)_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$ with  $A_j\subset A_{j+1}$ for alle $j$ 
the equality 
$$ \mu^\ast \Big( \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\Big)= \lim_{j\to \infty} \mu^\ast (A_j)$$

Some results which might be helpful

> - All measures are continuous from below
> - All metric outer measures are continuous from below

So I search for an outer measure which isn't continuous from below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let

$$\mu^\ast(A) = \begin{cases}
0\quad\;,\; A = \varnothing\\
1\quad\;,\; A \text{ is finite and nonempty}\\
\infty\quad, \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

on an infinite set $X$.

If $\bigcup A_j$ is infinite, either at least one $A_j$ is infinite, or infinitely many $A_j$ are nonempty, so

$$\mu^\ast\left(\bigcup A_j\right) \leqslant \sum \mu^\ast(A_j).$$

Let $A_j = \{x_k\colon 1 \leqslant k \leqslant j\}$ for a sequence of distinct $x_k$, then

$$\mu^\ast(A_j) = 1$$

for all $j$, but $\mu^\ast\left(\bigcup A_j\right) = \infty$.

Comment: Don't you mean $A_j=\bigcup_{k=1}^j \{ x_i\}$ for distinct $x_i$ ?

Comment: Ah, right. Sorry.

Comment: And why are those counterexamples always so easy once you have them ?

Comment: That's the nature of things, though I don't know why that is.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis They say everything looks trivial one you get the answer. =)

Comment: By the way if you apply the Caratheodory construction on this outer measure (Caratheodory grants you to make a measure out of every outer measure if you restrict it) the $\sigma$-Algebra you get is the trivial one (only the empty set and the whole set is inside) and the measure is 0 for the empty set and 1 (or $\infty$) for the whole set.